# First SF work (written) where the protagonist or antagonist take the name of the fallen angel, Abaddon

Tags: story-identification, history-of

There have been examples throughout SFF literature of using the names of the Fallen Angels for either characters or places.  In particular, John Bunyan utilised the name Abaddon in his [The Pilgrim's Progress](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Pilgrim%27s_Progress) (an allegorical poem rather than SFF).

Having recently re-read, Julian May's [The Saga of the Pliocene Exile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saga_of_Pliocene_Exile), and David Gemmell's [Wolf_in_Shadow](https://davidgemmell.fandom.com/wiki/Wolf_in_Shadow) there are further instances of a major character taking the name Abaddon instead of their actual names (Marc Remilliard in the first and Lawrence Welby in the latter).

Wolf in Shadow was first published in 1987, and the Non Born King (book 3 of the Saga of the Pliocene exile where Marc Remilliard is introduced) dates from 1983.

This got me thinking, is the Non Born King, the earliest example of a major character using the name Abaddon instead of their own?  If not, which is the earliest written work that is?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abaddon_in_popular_culture, although many of them seem to refer to the place, not the person.

Comment: Just to clarify, you're looking for a _character_ (not a place) who is _not_ the actual demon Abaddon, using that name as an _alias_, correct?

Comment: @davidw - that is correct, I'm looking for a character.

Answer (score 6):

If I remember correctly, there should be a story revised or collaborated on by H.P. Lovecraft which has a sinister house once inhabited by a very evil family. Going though the list of Lovecraft collaborations, I think that it might be "the Diary of Alonzo Typer".

The story mentions many sinister members of that family X, including one named Abaddon X, if I remember correctly.  Lovecraft died in 1937, and the story I think I have identified, "The Diary of Alonso Typer", was published in *Weird Tales*, February 1938 and republished later:

https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?69401

Of course Abaddon might be the person's real personal name. On the other hand, it might have been impossible for the family to give a child such a sinister official name, and the and Abaddon might be legally a nickname used instead of innocuous babtismial name.

Anyway, "The Diary of Alonzo Typer" is online:

https://www.hplovecraft.com/writings/texts/fiction/dat.aspx

And the diary entry for April 17, 1908 says:

> ...Probably it was easier to build than a Dutch colonial house - and then, too I remember that Dirck van der Heyl's wife was from Salem, a daughter of the unmentionable Abaddon Corey...

Anyway, this might count as an early example of a fictional character named Abaddon, even though Abaddon Corey lived a couple of centuries before the events in the story  and so was not a protagonist or antagonist.